# Nested loop fail in python

Tags: python

Sorry for daft newbie question but my nested loops wont work. It returns only the first iteration.  What have I missed??

I'm trying to grep for a multiple strings in my main file. I think I messed up the indentation but all the variations I try return errors.

```
f = open('GRCh37_genes_all_mod.txt', 'rU') # main search file
f1 = open('genes_regions_out.txt', 'a') #out file
f2 = open('gene_list.txt', 'r') # search list

for gene in f2:
    for line in f:
            if gene in line:
                    print line
                    f1.write(line)
```

Comment: You have to first iterated through the lines individually using `for gene in f2.readlines():` and the same for `f`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Oh yes. :) Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

You can only iterate through a file once. After the first time through `f`, the next time you try and run `for line in f`, you won't get any content.

If you want to iterate through a file's content multiple times, you can put that content into a list.

```
with open('GRCh37_genes_all_mod.txt', 'rU') as f:
    contents = list(f)

with open('gene_list.txt', 'r') as f:
    genes = list(f)

for gene in genes:
    for line in contents:
        ...
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Feel free to post alternative answers.

Comment: Thanks all.  Now I have working loops. I have tested @khelwood answer and this solved my problem.

Comment: While reading everything into memory works, it could also be done by simply rewinding the file which would use a lot less memory.

Answer (score 1):

After the first iteration, the file pointer is at the end of the file and the iterator is exhausted (calls to `next(f)` will raise `StopIteration`).

The simplest solution for this case is to reset the file pointer using `f.seek(0)`:

```
for gene in f2:
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f: 
       # ...
```

For other iterables (that might not be 'resetable'), if you know how many 'copies' you need, you can use `itertools.tee()`, or, if you know the iterable is finite (some iterable are infinite) and all it's content will fit in memory, you can just make a list of it as explained by Khelwood.

Comment: Both answer fix my initial error. Thank you. But both now have the added result of dumping non matches into the outputs after giving me correct ones.